Calculation of residence time in a continuous stirred tank reactor (CSTR)
Residence time tells us about the time reactants spend in a reactor. In a CSTR, spacetime is given by consumption upon consumption rate at the exit. Why do we take the rate at the exit only and not the average rate as it will give a more accurate time that the reactant spends in the reactor? By taking the exit rate we assume the whole time, the rate was constant and equal to the exit rate, which is wrong in the case of a non zero order reaction.

did you use an incorrect term? ... spacetime  has to do with the structure of the universe

@jsotola spacetime is also known as residence time in a flow reactor

Internet search indicates that the term  is two words space time

How would you measure the average rate as opposed to the rate at the exit?
